# Could not load type 'System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule'

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am having an issue that I am struggling to find out more information to help me diagnose my problem. I have downloaded my web forms application from TFS and the issue I am running into is the error message "Could not load type 'System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule'". Could someone possibly point me in the right direction to understand 1) why am I getting this error 2) how to correct and even 3) how to get around the issue to load my application. I am at an intermediate level using Asp.net and web forms, but I haven't come across this at all in the past. Thank you in advance.

[image: Exception]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be missing the System.Web.Routing assembly.  Open the references folder and see if there is a warning triangle icon on that particular assembly.

Digging around I see that it was bundled with the .net 3.5 service pack 1 but I would also think it would be included in newer versions of .net.  If you are running 3.5, install the service pack.

UPDATE: MORE INFO

In .net 4 it was moved into the System.Web assembly so you would definitely have it if you are running that version.  It makes me wonder what he version of the web forms app is [check the web.config] and what you currently have installed on your machine.

You can see what assembly an object is in by searching MSDN.  You can use the "previous" versions dropdown to see how it has changed over time or whether it was even available in previous versions.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutingmodule(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutingmodule%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much, William. I had been struggling with this all day - it turns out that I did not have .Net 3.5 installed but the application was in 3.5. I tried to download and install 3.5 with sp1, but could not get the .exe to launch. I wound up changing the framework on the application to 4.0 and it allowed me to launch and proceed with debugging. Thanks, again.